SignaturDoesNotMatch when trying Multipart upload in AWS S3 bucket in flutter
The problem you're facing is related to AWS S3 multipart upload signature calculation. Specifically, the error SignatureDoesNotMatch indicates that the AWS signature you're generating does not match the expected signature calculated by AWS. This error often occurs due to issues in the signing process or discrepancies in the request being made.
`import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:xml/xml.dart';

// Replace these with your AWS credentials
const String bucketName = '*********';
const String region = 'us-east-1';
const String accessKey = '*********';
const String secretKey = '*********';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'S3 Multipart Upload',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String statusMessage = '';

  Future<void> s3Upload() async {
    // Pick a file
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    if (result == null || result.files.isEmpty) {
      print('No file selected.');
      return;
    }

    PlatformFile platformFile = result.files.first;
    print('File name: ${platformFile.name}');
    print('File path: ${platformFile.path}');

    Uint8List? fileBytes = platformFile.bytes;
    if (fileBytes == null) {
      print('File bytes are null. Attempting to load file from path.');

      if (platformFile.path != null) {
        try {
          final file = File(platformFile.path!);
          fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();
          if (fileBytes == null) {
            print('Failed to read file bytes from path.');
            return;
          }
          print('File bytes length: ${fileBytes.length}');
        } catch (e) {
          print('Error reading file from path: $e');
          return;
        }
      } else {
        print('File path is null.');
        return;
      }
    } else {
      print('File bytes length: ${fileBytes.length}');
    }

    final filePath = Uri.encodeComponent(platformFile.name);
    print('File path: $filePath');

    final now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
    final date = DateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(now);
    final amzDate = DateFormat('yyyyMMdd\'T\'HHmmss\'Z\'').format(now);
    final scope = '$date/$region/s3/aws4_request';

    // Step 1: Initiate Multipart Upload
    final initiateResponse = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://$bucketName.s3.$region.amazonaws.com/$filePath?uploads'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': _generateAuthorizationHeader(
          method: 'POST',
          canonicalUri: '/$filePath',
          queryParameters: {'uploads': ''},
          payloadHash: 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
          amzDate: amzDate,
          scope: scope,
        ),
        'x-amz-date': amzDate,
        'x-amz-content-sha256': 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
      },
    );

    if (initiateResponse.statusCode != 200) {
      print('Failed to initiate upload: ${initiateResponse.body}');
      setState(() {
        statusMessage = 'Failed to initiate upload: ${initiateResponse.body}';
      });
      return;
    }

    final xmlDoc = XmlDocument.parse(initiateResponse.body);
    final uploadId = xmlDoc.findAllElements('UploadId').first.text;
    print('Upload ID: $uploadId');

    // Step 2: Upload parts using pre-signed URLs
    int fileSize = fileBytes.length;
    final int chunkSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
    int numChunks = (fileSize / chunkSize).ceil();
    print('File size: $fileSize bytes');
    print('Chunk size: $chunkSize bytes');
    print('Number of chunks: $numChunks');

    List<String> etags = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < numChunks; i++) {
      int start = i * chunkSize;
      int end = (start + chunkSize < fileSize) ? start + chunkSize : fileSize;

      Uint8List chunkBytes = fileBytes.sublist(start, end);

      final partNumber = i + 1;
      final presignedUrl = await _getPresignedUrlForPart(
        method: 'PUT',
        partNumber: partNumber,
        uploadId: uploadId,
        filePath: filePath,
        amzDate: amzDate,
        scope: scope,
      );

      var response = await http.put(
        presignedUrl,
        headers: {'x-amz-content-sha256': sha256.convert(chunkBytes).toString()},
        body: chunkBytes,
      );

      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        print('Failed to upload chunk $partNumber: ${response.body}');
        setState(() {
          statusMessage = 'Failed to upload chunk $partNumber: ${response.body}';
        });
        return;
      }

      // Collect ETags for each part
      String etag = response.headers['etag']!;
      etags.add('<Part><PartNumber>$partNumber</PartNumber><ETag>$etag</ETag></Part>');
    }

    // Step 3: Complete Multipart Upload
    final completeRequestPayload = '<CompleteMultipartUpload>${etags.join()}</CompleteMultipartUpload>';

    final completeResponse = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://$bucketName.s3.$region.amazonaws.com/$filePath?uploadId=$uploadId'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': _generateAuthorizationHeader(
          method: 'POST',
          canonicalUri: '/$filePath',
          queryParameters: {'uploadId': uploadId},
          payloadHash: sha256.convert(utf8.encode(completeRequestPayload)).toString(),
          amzDate: amzDate,
          scope: scope,
        ),
        'x-amz-date': amzDate,
        'x-amz-content-sha256': sha256.convert(utf8.encode(completeRequestPayload)).toString(),
      },
      body: completeRequestPayload,
    );

    if (completeResponse.statusCode != 200) {
      print('Failed to complete upload: ${completeResponse.body}');
      setState(() {
        statusMessage = 'Failed to complete upload: ${completeResponse.body}';
      });
      return;
    }

    print('Upload complete!');
    setState(() {
      statusMessage = 'Upload complete!';
    });
  }

  String _generateAuthorizationHeader({
    required String method,
    required String canonicalUri,
    required Map<String, String> queryParameters,
    required String payloadHash,
    required String amzDate,
    required String scope,
  }) {
    final headers = {
      'host': '$bucketName.s3.$region.amazonaws.com',
      'x-amz-date': amzDate,
      'x-amz-content-sha256': payloadHash,
    };

    final signedHeaders = headers.keys.map((key) => key.toLowerCase()).join(';');
    final canonicalRequest = [
      method,
      canonicalUri,
      queryParameters.entries
          .map((entry) => '${Uri.encodeComponent(entry.key)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(entry.value)}')
          .join('&'),
      headers.entries
          .map((entry) => '${entry.key.toLowerCase()}:${entry.value.trim()}')
          .join('\n'),
      '',
      signedHeaders,
      payloadHash,
    ].join('\n');

    final hashedCanonicalRequest = sha256.convert(utf8.encode(canonicalRequest)).toString();
    final stringToSign = [
      'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
      amzDate,
      scope,
      hashedCanonicalRequest,
    ].join('\n');

    final signingKey = _deriveSigningKey(
      secretKey: secretKey,
      date: DateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(DateTime.now().toUtc()),
      region: region,
      service: 's3',
    );
    final signature = Hmac(sha256, signingKey).convert(utf8.encode(stringToSign)).toString();

    return 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=$accessKey/$scope, SignedHeaders=$signedHeaders, Signature=$signature';
  }

  Future<Uri> _getPresignedUrlForPart({
    required String method,
    required int partNumber,
    required String uploadId,
    required String filePath,
    required String amzDate,
    required String scope,
  }) async {
    final queryParameters = {
      'partNumber': partNumber.toString(),
      'uploadId': uploadId,
    };

    final headers = {
      'host': '$bucketName.s3.$region.amazonaws.com',
      'x-amz-date': amzDate,
      'x-amz-content-sha256': 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
    };

    final signedHeaders = headers.keys.map((key) => key.toLowerCase()).join(';');
    final canonicalRequest = [
      method,
      '/$filePath',
      queryParameters.entries
          .map((entry) => '${Uri.encodeComponent(entry.key)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(entry.value)}')
          .join('&'),
      headers.entries
          .map((entry) => '${entry.key.toLowerCase()}:${entry.value.trim()}')
          .join('\n'),
      '',
      signedHeaders,
      'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
    ].join('\n');

    final hashedCanonicalRequest = sha256.convert(utf8.encode(canonicalRequest)).toString();
    final stringToSign = [
      'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
      amzDate,
      scope,
      hashedCanonicalRequest,
    ].join('\n');

    final signingKey = _deriveSigningKey(
      secretKey: secretKey,
      date: DateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(DateTime.now().toUtc()),
      region: region,
      service: 's3',
    );
    final signature = Hmac(sha256, signingKey).convert(utf8.encode(stringToSign)).toString();

    final queryParams = queryParameters.entries.map((e) => '${Uri.encodeComponent(e.key)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(e.value)}').join('&');
    return Uri.parse('https://$bucketName.s3.$region.amazonaws.com/$filePath?$queryParams')
        .replace(queryParameters: {
      'x-amz-date': amzDate,
      'x-amz-content-sha256': 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
      'Authorization': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=$accessKey/$scope, SignedHeaders=$signedHeaders, Signature=$signature',
    });
  }

  List<int> _deriveSigningKey({
    required String secretKey,
    required String date,
    required String region,
    required String service,
  }) {
    List<int> kDate = _hmacSha256(utf8.encode('AWS4$secretKey'), utf8.encode(date));
    List<int> kRegion = _hmacSha256(kDate, utf8.encode(region));
    List<int> kService = _hmacSha256(kRegion, utf8.encode(service));
    return _hmacSha256(kService, utf8.encode('aws4_request'));
  }

  List<int> _hmacSha256(List<int> key, List<int> message) {
    return Hmac(sha256, key).convert(message).bytes;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('S3 Multipart Upload'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: s3Upload,
                child: Text('Upload File'),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text(statusMessage),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}`

this is my code which basically takes any file from the user and divides it into chunks to be uploaded into the AWS i was trying to upload a file larger than 5GB through a flutter app. now i have tried alot of things as well as gpt but it wont help at all. Please i need a solution
I was trying to send request to upload a large file to my AWS S3 Private bucket but when sending request i am reciecved with a SignatureDoesNotMatch error in my flutter run console. WHat to do
